# Passing a constant as a C# generic type parameter

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics

I have an NHibernate IUserType which I'm trying to use to bind a couple of fixed size double[] fields (of different size) to single database column as BLOBs. I have the following code but somehow I need to pass it a constant integer so it knows how big the array should be. I don't think there's a way to instantiate this type in a custom way at runtime so the size really needs to be part of the type itself. I'd rather not have two copies of this ugly class if I can avoid it!

```
public class DoubleArrayUserType<Size> : NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserType
{
    private int _size = sizeof(Size);

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        if (cached == null)
            return null;

        if (cached == DBNull.Value)
            return null;

        if (!(cached is byte[]))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var arrayBytes = cached as byte[];
        var arrayStream = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(arrayBytes));

        var values = new double[_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
            values[i] = arrayStream.ReadDouble();

        return values;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return DBNull.Value;

        if (value == DBNull.Value)
            return DBNull.Value;

        if (!(value is double[]))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var values = value as double[];
        var bytes = new List<byte>(sizeof(double) * _size);
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
            bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(values[i]));
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }

    public NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType[] { NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlTypeFactory.GetBinaryBlob(1) }; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're aware that the text of your question implies that you want to do something that is impossible in .Net? You might want to consider changing it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't divide the length of arrayBytes by the size of double?

Comment: You say you don't want **two** copies of the ugly class. Does that mean you only need two different values of `_size`? What are those two values? Maybe you could use `int` and `long` respectively, for your `Size` type parameter?

Comment: For now, I need 6 and 8, but that could change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a controversial solution (expecting downvotes!), it doesn't yield a constant, though.  I'm sure you will be able to solve your problem a different way, as well:

```
public interface IHasSize{
  int Size { get; }
}

public class MySize : IHasSize { 
  public int Size { get { return 4; } }
}

public class RequiresASize<TSize> where TSize : IHasSize, new()
{
  private int _size = new TSize().Size;
}

public class ProvidesASize : RequiresASize<MySize>{
  //_size in base class will be 4
}
```

So `RequiresASize<TSize>` is your big class in your question.  I'm using inheritance via the `ProvidesASize` type at the end to demonstrate how it would work.

Comment: Yours is a bit more verbose than mine, but unlike mine it looks like it would work. :P
    `struct iTRAQArray { readonly double[] values = new double[8]; }
    struct TMTArray { readonly double[] values = new double[6]; }

    public class iTRAQArrayUserType : DoubleArrayUserType<iTRAQArray> {}
    public class TMTArrayUserType : DoubleArrayUserType<TMTArray> {}`

Comment: I suppose you could say this technique is similar to the whole 'type traits' mechanism used in boost and indeed 'newer' C++ code.  I've never thought of doing it before and I'm still not *entirely* convinced that it can't be done another way; but if it does work then glad to help :)

Comment: It's a little strange that `RequiresASize<MySize4>` and `RequiresASize<SomeOtherSize4>` are different as types even if both `MySize4` and `SomeOtherSize4` implement the `Size` property by returning 4. You could write a static constructor for `RequiresASize<TSize>` to check that the `TSize` type is never someone else's class.

Comment: Yes true - or you can make the interface internal and then use an explicit interface implementation if the implementing type needs to be public; although that would entirely depend upon the project structure I guess.

Comment: Why not skip the generic and just go with a descendant of DoubleArrayUserType with a virtual size?

Comment: @Neil A fair point (and I have said I don't expect this is actually the best solution); although there are a couple of reasons where you won't do that in the general case - 1) if you need to seal the generic; but more importantly 2) if you need that `size` value in the constructor; that would involve invoking a virtual at construction, which could go wrong for the inheritor.  Neither of these apply in this case, by the looks of it, though.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan both reasonable points. I think my point is more one for the original questioner since we do not know the full set of constraints that they are under.

Comment: @Neil - I understand - and I totally agree with you as well