# Generics: Passing an int value instead of type

Tags: c#, generics

Here is the issue I am trying to solve. I need to expose a set of custom types to my users. To give some examples:

```
var int2 = new FixedArray<int, VM2>(); // <=> ImmutableArray<int> / Length = 2
var double3 = new FixedArray<double, VM3>(); // <=> ImmutableArray<double> / Length = 3
var ushort6 = new FixedArray<ushort, VM6>(); // <=> ImmutableArray<ushort> / Length = 6
[...]
```

To avoid boilerplate code, I tried to use generics for the second parameter, and ended up with something like this:

```
sealed class FixedArray<T, VM> : IStructuralComparable where T : struct where VM : IVM, new()
{
    public T[] array { get; init; }
    public FixedArray()
    {
        VM vm = new VM(); // hopefully the compiler will do something smart
        array = new T[vm.Value];
    }

    public int CompareTo(object? other, IComparer comparer) => ((IStructuralComparable)array).CompareTo(other, comparer);
}
```

with:

```
interface IVM
{
    int Value { get; }
}
sealed class VM2 : IVM
{
    public VM2() { Value = 2; }
    public int Value { get; }
}
sealed class VM3 : IVM
{
    public VM3() { Value = 3; }
    public int Value { get; }
}
sealed class VM6 : IVM
{
    public VM6() { Value = 6; }
    public int Value { get; }
}
```

Is there any other trick to pass an integer in my case (avoid highly redundant code in between the different array size) ?

---

Update:

VM can be:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 8
- 16
- 24
- 1-2
- 1-3
- 1-8
- 1-32
- 1-n
- 2-2n
- 2-n
- 3-3n
- 3-n

Comment: So you want the size of the array to be part of the _type_?

Comment: You can shorten your `IVM` implementors to `sealed class VM2 : IVM { public int Value => 2; }`. No need for the explicit constructor declaration. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: Yes precisley !

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742947/passing-a-constant-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-parameter)

Comment: One trick is to use C++, where templates do cater to exactly this sort of thing, while generics don't. Less facetiously, doing more with `ReadOnlySpan` and `stackalloc` arrays may pay off more than wrapping regular arrays in custom types (if your use case supports it, of course).

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to do this in c#. Generics are simply less flexible than c++ templates.

If there are a few array lengths that are very commonly used it is somewhat common to just declare separate types. A typical example would be Vector2/3/4. This also makes it easier to add methods and properties that are only relevant for a specific length.

I'm not really seeing the advantage of the `VM` type parameter. As far as I can see it should be simpler to omit it and just do

```
interface IFixedArray<T> where T : struct
{
    T[] array {get;}
}
sealed class FixedArray2<T> : IFixedArray<T>
{
    public T[] array {get;}
    public FixedArray2() => array = new T[2];
}
```

You still need to declare a class per size, but you get rid of one generic type parameter. Methods may be implemented as extension methods to avoid duplication, but that might not be an alternative if you need to implement some interface. If that is the case a common base-class might be an alternative.

Comment: I have 18 possible VMs...

Comment: @malat: there are various options for code generation in C# -- T4 templates and of course the new [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk) spring to mind. That would make this approach viable as long as you have a fixed number of types, be it 8 or 18. It fails if you have to support any arbitrary size statically, of course.

Comment: The link to [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) got unnecessarily truncated, I see.